# PHPStorm .sass, .css and Deployment Settings Issue

Tags: deployment, configuration, phpstorm

So I use PHPStorm, and for CSS I use SASS that complies to CSS. I have questions mainly about workflow.

1. I have things setup (or so I thought) that when I deploy everything/one file, .sass .scss etc files WONT be uploaded. However they still do when I use my shortcut to upload.
   [image: Shortcut]
   [image: THE GOGGLES THEY DO NOTHING]
2. How do I make it so I can use my shortcut to upload the main.css and not the .scss file(s) without having to manually go into my main.css files every time first? Even sync uploads the damned scss files so I dont know whats up.

Comment: **1.** You did the exclusions wrong: `.sass` will exclude just THAT file and not `abc.sass`. To exclude all `.sass` files you have to use `*.sass` *(just as hint below that field says -- nothing more, nothing less)* **2.** No way (very unfortunately) -- but sync will be working properly now (after you fix your #1). Automatic upload may also do the job just fine (but you will have to tick "Upload external changes" option as well).

Comment: Thanks can't believe I missed the *. I even remember reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** You did the exclusions wrong: `.sass` will exclude just THAT file and not any other, e.g. `abc.sass`.

To exclude all `.sass` files you have to use **`*.sass`** (*just as hint below that field says -- nothing more, nothing less*).

**2.** No way (unfortunately) -- but sync will be working properly now (after you fix your #1).

Automatic upload should also do the job just fine (but you will have to tick `Upload external changes` option as well).